# How to add some non-standard font to a website?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

Is there a way to add some custom font on a website without using images, [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash) or some other graphics?

For example, I was working on a wedding website, and I found a lot of nice fonts for that subject. But I can't find the right way to add that font on the server. And how do I include that font with CSS into the HTML? Is this possible to do without graphics?

Comment: Since this question was asked, `@font-face` has become much more widely supported and is recommended for general use. You just have to be aware that IE requires fonts in a different format to other browsers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219916/is-font-face-usable-now

Comment: Make sure you have the right to distribute the font!

Comment: Visit http://typekit.com/, or for the cheap http://www.fontsquirrel.com/

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050640/how-does-iefix-solve-web-fonts-loading-in-ie6-ie8

Comment: www.fontsquirrel.com seems great to generate the required font files & create a good bullet-proof @fontface syntax (same as the recommended http://www.fontspring.com/blog/fixing-ie9-font-face-problems)

Answer (score 564, accepted):

This could be done via CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: "My Custom Font";
    src: url(http://www.example.org/mycustomfont.ttf) format("truetype");
}
p.customfont { 
    font-family: "My Custom Font", Verdana, Tahoma;
}
</style>
<p class="customfont">Hello world!</p>
```

It is [supported for all of the regular browsers](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) if you use TrueType-Fonts (TTF), the Web Open Font Format (WOFF) or Embedded Opentype (EOT).

Comment: Note: Looks like the font-face tag also is a part of CSS3 and not just CSS2. See http://www.css3.info/webkit-has-web-fonts-support/ for more information.

Comment: It's not useless since it's standard : the more you implement it, the more it will likely be implemented by browsers. That does not mean you should not find another way to compensate, but using this as a complement seems good to me.

Comment: Firefox 3.1 does support @font-face, though.

Comment: @brendanjerwin: updated version of your link - http://brendanjerwin.com/development/web/2009/03/03/embedding-fonts.html

Comment: @brendanjerwin: updated the updated version of your link -http://brendanjerwin.com/blog/2009/03/03/embedding-fonts/

Comment: @e-satis: "It's not useless since it's standard : the more you implement it, the more it will likely be implemented by browsers." We are facing something of a large-scale (philosopher's) "prisoner's dilemma" here. If the web as a whole adopts a proposed standard, it is more likely that browsers comply. However the individual best optimization for inconsistent support is often not to just do what it would be best if everyone did, and that's even without taking into account "embrace and extend" and like menaces.

Comment: i have added same but cant adding the font ? or may have i added wrong way ?

Comment: Couldn't we dispense with the broken links and just put the pertinent info here?  Create the .eot file by downloading MS Web Embedding Font Tool (WEFT) @font-face { font-family: "Vineta BT"; src: url(http://MyServer/MyFontLocation/VINETAB0.eot); }

Comment: see the bulletproof standard @font-face syntax http://www.fontspring.com/blog/fixing-ie9-font-face-problems

Comment: Hey guys, guess what? It's now almost 2016! It's now supported widely! Yay! Glad, I found this answer this late. Haha.

Comment: How to link on a local path?

Comment: @EdwardBlack Just leave out the `//`.

Comment: NOTE: If the font file name contains space, you must use quotes, like this: `url('the font.ttf')` or `url("the font.ttf")`

Answer (score 141):

You can add some fonts via [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/).

Technically, the fonts are hosted at Google and you link them in the HTML header. Then, you can use them freely in CSS with [`@font-face`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule) ([read about it](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/)).

For example:

In the `<head>` section:

```
 <link href=' http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then in CSS:

```
h1 { font-family: 'Droid Sans', arial, serif; }
```

---

The solution seems quite reliable (even [Smashing Magazine uses it for an article title.](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/)). There are, however, not so many fonts available so far in [Google Font Directory](http://www.google.com/fonts/).

Comment: In July 2014, google has expanded the fonts and included Google Noto fonts which support most languages https://www.google.com/get/noto/#/ . Abobe has supported this open font initiative supporting all languages http://blog.typekit.com/2014/07/15/introducing-source-han-sans/

Comment: it seems (Google web fonts) doesn't support .eot and .woff and .svg versions of fonts. it just supports .ttf version of fonts!

Comment: Note, that at this time, it does not work with type='text/css' for me but only with type='text/html'.

Answer (score 85):

The way to go is using the @font-face CSS declaration which allows authors to specify online fonts to display text on their web pages. By allowing authors to provide their own fonts, @font-face eliminates the need to depend on the limited number of fonts users have installed on their computers.

Take a look at the following table:

[image]

As you can see, there are several formats that you need to know about mainly due to cross-browser compatibility. The scenario in mobile devices isn't much different.

### Solutions:

**1 - Full browser compatibility**

This is the method with the deepest support possible right now:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

**2 - Most of the browser**

Things are [shifting heavily toward WOFF](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff) though, so you can probably get away with:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('myfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
       url('myfont.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Chrome 4+, Firefox 3.5, Opera 10+, Safari 3—5 */
}
```

**3 - Only the latest browsers**

Or even just WOFF.
You then use it like this:

```
body {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont', Fallback, sans-serif;
}
```

### References and Further reading:

That's mainly what you need to know about implementing this feature. If you want to research more on the subject I'll encourage to take a look at the following resources. Most of what I put here is extracted from the following

- [Using Font Face](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) (Very recommended)
- [Bulletproof @font-face syntax](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/)
- [Can i use @font-face web fonts ?](http://caniuse.com/fontface)
- [How to archive Cross-Browser @font-face support](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/)
- [@font-face at the CSS Mozilla Developer Network](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/)

Comment: The extremely handy [Font Squirrel tool](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) can generate the CSS needed for full-browser support. It even lets you upload the font as any one of these formats, converts it to all the other formats, and lets you download them all. It's a life saver when it comes to custom fonts.

Comment: What does `svgFontName` stand for? Should I change it to my font family name or leave it as is?

Answer (score 18):

If by non standard font, you mean custom font of a standard format, here's how I do it, and it works for all browsers I've checked so far:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: TempestaSevenCondensed;
    src: url("../fonts/pf_tempesta_seven_condensed.eot") /* EOT file for IE */
}
@font-face {
    font-family: TempestaSevenCondensed;
    src: url("../fonts/pf_tempesta_seven_condensed.ttf") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}
```

so you'll just need both the ttf and eot fonts. Some tools available online can make the conversion.

But if you want to attach font in a non standard format (bitmaps etc), I can't help you.

Comment: Online tool example: http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ttf2eot.cgi Offline tool example: http://code.google.com/p/ttf2eot/wiki/Demo - it should also be possible to use [WOFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woff) fonts.

Answer (score 11):

I've found that the easiest way to have non-standard fonts on a website is to use **[sIFR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Inman_Flash_Replacement)**

It does involve the use of a Flash object that contains the font, but it degrades nicely to standard text / font if Flash is not installed.

The style is set in your CSS, and JavaScript sets up the Flash replacement for your text.

**Edit: (I still recommend using images for non-standard fonts as sIFR adds time to a project and can require maintenance).**

Comment: What a terrible idea ! I have flash in my browser but flashblock too. On that website, my browser display an horrible defaced page. Flash should stay something that you use for big animations or movies. Too much flash is wery anoying and visualy, my my...

Comment: @e-satis: How so? Personally, I never notice the difference between a page that uses sIFR and one that doesn't, aside from the subtle text rendering differences. I think it's a great idea, honestly, although `@font-face` is much better where supported.

Comment: "Edit: (I still recommend using images for non-standard fonts as sIFR adds time to a project and can require maintenance)." very well said.  sIFR is a really cool technique but it seems to require a lot to get the EXACT look you want.  If you have the time to learn and master this technique I'd highly recommend it.  But if you are looking for a quick and easy font-replacement technique I'd use image replacement or even the @font-face css property

Comment: Adobe Flash is dead; no longer a good idea.

Answer (score 11):

The article *[Font-face in IE: Making Web Fonts Work](http://jontangerine.com/log/2008/10/font-face-in-ie-making-web-fonts-work)* says it works with all three major browsers.

Here is a sample I got working: http://brendanjerwin.com/test_font.html

More discussion is in *[Embedding Fonts](http://brendanjerwin.com/development/web/2009/03/03/embedding-fonts.html)*.

Answer (score 10):

[Typeface.js](http://typeface.neocracy.org/) and [Cufon](http://wiki.github.com/sorccu/cufon) are two other interesting options. They are JavaScript components that render special font data in JSON format (which you can convert from [TrueType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType) or [OpenType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType) formats on their web sites) via the new <canvas> element in all newer browsers except Internet Explorer and via [VML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language) in Internet Explorer.

The main problem with both (as of now) is that selecting text does not work or at least works only quite awkwardly.

Still, it is very nice for headlines. Body text... I don't know.

And it's surprisingly fast.

Comment: Another interesting option is typekit.com Similar concept.

Answer (score 8):

Or you could try [sIFR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Inman_Flash_Replacement). I know it uses Flash, but only if available. If Flash isn't available, it displays the original text in its original (CSS) font.

Answer (score 4):

The technique that the W3C has recommended for do this is called "embedding" and is well described by the three articles here: [Embedding Fonts](http://www.allgraphicdesign.com/downloadfonts/fontsarticles/embeddingfonts/csswebsitespages.html).  In my limited experiments, I have found this process error-prone and have had limited success in making it function in a multi-browser environment.

Answer (score 4):

Safari and Internet Explorer both support the CSS @font-face rule, however they support two different embedded font types. Firefox is planning to support the same type as Apple some time soon. SVG can embed fonts but isn't that widely supported yet (without a plugin).

I think the most portable solution I've seen is to use a JavaScript function to replace headings etc. with an image generated and cached on the server with your font of choice -- that way you simply update the text and don't have to stuff around in Photoshop.

Comment: This does not have to be done with JavaScript. I know that a lot of people like to use JavaScript for quite a few stuff nowadays, but a standard CSS technique may be more appropriate here. See http://www.sitepoint.com/article/header-images-css-xhtml/

Comment: I'm sorry if there's confusion, the technique refers not to the method of image replacement which, as you say, can be CSS. It is about generating graphics representing a given string in a particular font/style, on the fly, at the server -- obviating the need to create these manually.

Answer (score 4):

If you use ASP.NET, it's really easy to generate image based fonts without actually having to install (as in adding to the installed font base) fonts on the server by using:

```
PrivateFontCollection pfont = new PrivateFontCollection();
pfont.AddFontFile(filename);
FontFamily ff = pfont.Families[0];
```

and then drawing with that font onto a `Graphics`.

Comment: well, yes... And you user can forget about copying and pasting. And zooming too, in old browsers. I don't even talk about bandwidth issues !

Comment: Yeah, ok, and the question specified that it was going to be using it for content text? No it didnt, it was a general question, and this was a general answer. Small snippets of text, headers, etc, dont take up lots of bandwidth. Sheesh, get a grip!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it only works in Internet Explorer, but a quick Google search for "html embed fonts" yields http://www.spoono.com/html/tutorials/tutorial.php?id=19

If you want to stay platform-agnostic (and you should!) you'll have to use images, or else just use a standard font.

Answer (score 3):

I did a bit of research and dug up *[Dynamic Text Replacement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dynatext/)* (published 2004-06-15).

This technique uses images, but it appears to be "hands free". You write your text, and you let a few automated scripts do automated find-and-replace on the page for you on the fly.

It has some limitations, but it is probably one of the easier choices (and more browser compatible) than all the rest I've seen.

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to use WOFF fonts - example [here](https://encrypted.pcode.nl/blog/wp-content/themes/simplest-pcode/style.css)

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Plakat Fraktur';
src: url('/resources/fonts/plakat-fraktur-black-modified.woff') format('woff');
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just simply provide the link to actual font like this and you will be good to go

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat'   rel='stylesheet'>
<style>
body {
font-family: 'Montserrat';font-size: 22px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Montserrat</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A good simple alternative. And you're sure to have the rights to use it. See https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started

Answer (score 2):

See the article *[50 Useful Design Tools For Beautiful Web Typography](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/01/27/css-typographic-tools-and-techniques/)* for alternative methods.

I have only used [Cufon](http://wiki.github.com/sorccu/cufon/). I have found it reliable and very easy to use, so I've stuck with it.

Answer (score 2):

**Typeface.js JavaScript Way:**

> With typeface.js you can embed custom
>   fonts in your web pages so you don't
>   have to render text to images
>
> Instead of creating images or using
>   flash just to show your site's graphic
>   text in the font you want, you can use
>   typeface.js and write in plain HTML
>   and CSS, just as if your visitors had
>   the font installed locally.

http://typeface.neocracy.org/

Answer (score 2):

If you have a file of your font, then you will need to add more formats of that font for other browsers.

For this purpose I use font generator like [Fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) it provides all the font formats & its @font-face CSS, you will only need to just drag & drop it into your CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

```
@font-face {
font-family: "CustomFont";
src: url("CustomFont.eot");
src: url("CustomFont.woff") format("woff"),
url("CustomFont.otf") format("opentype"),
url("CustomFont.svg#filename") format("svg");
}
```

Comment: Please explain why/how this solves the problem. See [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

easy solution is to use @fontface in css

```
@font-face {
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url(fileLocation);} 

div{
    font-family: myfirstfont;}
```

Comment: Please ensure, that your answer adds **new insights** or **refined approaches** based on previous answers. If your answer contains a subtle but relevant benefit – please, **elaborate** on it. If it doesn't please consider to remove your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@import url(url)` to import web fonts. You must replace `url` with the font source (full web source).

Comment: `@import` works for **stylesheets containing `@font-face` rules**. E.g  `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato')`. You can't import font files directly.

Comment: Sorry, I will make it right...