# CSS Code working on Mac browsers but not on Windows browsers?

Tags: css, windows, macos

I have the following CSS:

```
font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-UltraLight', 'Helvetica Neue UltraLight', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 100; letter-spacing: 1px; }
```

It works on all Mac browsers (Chrome, Safari) But I opened my project on Chrome and Internet explorer on Windows, it displays the font as bold rather than light. I'm not sure how to fix this but I need the design to work cross platform with the design that appears on mac.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've tried using arial but arial doesn't become light on both mac *and* windows.

Comment: The font you're using isn't available on Windows or Linux pltforms by default. If you want a specific font you need to include a declaration in your CSS. NeueHelvetica is a Monotype font and will be chargeable.

Comment: @mikew I've tried using arial but arial doesn't become light on both mac _and_ windows?

Comment: Take alook at [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts). You might find a suitable licence-free font you can use there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font you see on Windows is not bold, it is just regular Arial.

In almost all Windows systems, the first available font family among those listed in the `font-family` value is Arial. Since Arial has no typeface of weight 100, or of any weight less than 400, the normal (400) weight typeface is used instead, by the [font matching algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-style-matching).

Fonts in standard distributions of Windows generally lack typefaces with weight less than normal. So  to use lighter typefaces, you would need to use downloadable fonts (web fonts) via `@font-face`. See e.g. [Is @font-face usable now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219916/is-font-face-usable-now)
 (SO has many specific questions on using `@font-face`, check them if you run into specific problems with it).

Comment: so what font face is matching arial (that's free) and can also be downloaded as a ttf or otf?

Comment: Arial is not free (it’s widely available, in various versions, but that’s a different issues). Font matching in the sense you mean is a typographic, esthetic, and stylistic question, outside the scope of SO. Check out Google Web Fonts, as others have suggested. (Most fonts there have just 1 or 2 weights, but some come with an impressive repertoire of weights.)

Comment: thanks, I understand the issue now and have found a suitable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The font-family property inform the browser that it's needed to use that font. If there is no path for it, it will check if the system have that one.

In order to be able to have a font that will work on all systems, you need to use the @font-face property.

This last one will allow you to specify path for all the format font, that most of the browsers will download to display it correctly. (For your information all recent browser support it)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFont';
    src: url('myFont.eot');
    src: url('myFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('myFont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('myFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('myFont.svg#myFont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

If you want more information about that property you can check the reference here:

> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Unfortunetly in your case the font HelveticaNeue is copyrighted, you need to buy the rights to be able to use it as a webfont.

You can take a look here about pricing:
http://www.fonts.com/search/all-fonts?searchtext=HelveticaNeue#product_top

Also, if you have already the right and have one of the format that you wish to convert to a webfont, you can accomplish that here:

> http://www.fontsquirrel.com/

Finally, if you prefer you can use Google Fonts that will host the files for you, and you will just have a small script to insert inside your pages:

> http://www.google.com/fonts

Comment: ok, so, i think this is a bit off of your answer but I tried using arial. the only issue is, on windows font-weight isn't working? what shall I do?

Comment: font-weight: bold; only is working on most of the browser, changing the value to a small one like you wish to have thin one doesn't act the same... Firefox seems to use it, chrome not...

I advise you to find a similar font, I think Lato can suit your need, the light version have nice cut :)
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/lato?q%5Bterm%5D=Lato&q%5Bsearch_check%5D=Y

Answer (score 0):

You can use web fonts (free or paid) as suggested by others, or just use a nice font stack that is likely to cover all bases. CSS Tricks has a nice set of them: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/font-stacks/

In terms of font weight, your CSS specifies a very light font weight:

```
font-weight: 100;
```

So if you want to use bold Arial instead, you need to change that.

Comment: That is not cross-browser compatible.... And worst, doesn't have the same behavior for a specific browser on several systems....