# Embedding fonts in css file

Tags: css, fonts

HI everyone i am new to this css i am developing a website for that site i am using kannada fonts but i wnat to embed the fonts in css how to embed that can any one please give sugessions and solutions .. thanks in advance

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-website  similar questions at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=embedding+fonts+html+css

Answer (score 2):

[This is a great guide to cross-browser `@font-face`](http://randsco.com/index.php/2009/07/04/p680)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can embed them, but you should be able to use the `@font-face` to pull down your fonts. But it does not work in all browsers so beware.