# How could i use a specific font for my web site

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add some non standard font to website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-website)

I am working on new project.
In this web site the client used a font (Volta Regular).
Please tell me how I can use it. This font is missing on my computer.
How can I use it? This problem would come with all machine. How could I adjust it through CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use downloadable fonts which are described in this [AListApart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/cssatten) article (scroll down to the part titled "Web Fonts: the code you'll use"). But be careful. Browser support is still spotty so you'll want to provide a web safe default font for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, check out [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=en/CSS/%40font-face), a CSS based solution and [`cufon`](http://wiki.github.com/sorccu/cufon/about), a JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 0):

First download the specific font in net and past into your project folder.

For css, use this link:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-website
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out fontsquirrel.com

They have some pre-made @font-face kits and also a generator that will let you supply your own font (just make sure it is licensed for use on the web).

Answer (score 0):

If it's [the font](http://www.fonthaus.com/fonts/urw/volta/ur13304) I'm thinking of: I'm no lawyer & this isn't Copyright Overflow, but the font isn't free and the license seems pretty clear that @font-face embedding is not okay.

In that case, either 1) buy the font and make images with it (if it's just for a logo / heading); or  2) tell the client that the font isn't suitable for web use and ask them to pick something more [common](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html) (or at least legally embeddable) instead.