# Is there a way to use custom font saved in fonts directory in our web directory?

Tags: css

I am trying to do something like this

font-family: url('fonts/myfont.ttf');

You might think this is a stupid question, but if there is a way tell me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add some non standard font to website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at this myself:

http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, check out [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=en/CSS/%40font-face), a CSS based solution and [`cufon`](http://wiki.github.com/sorccu/cufon/about), a JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into sIFR:

http://novemberborn.net/sifr3

Comment: Cufon or @font-face are better options now.