# If I want to use a specific font that I know it is not available in most of the user's computer

Tags: java, html, css

If I want to use a specific font that I know it is not available in most of the user's computer, is it possoble to embed the font in my web site in some way? I have gone to some web site using special fonts as text, but not as image. I wonder how it works.

Thanks 
Mayur

Comment: http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/05/introducing-google-font-api-google-font.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FDcni+%28Google+Code+Blog%29&utm_content=Google+Reader Also check out @font-face

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add some non standard font to website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-website)

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this myself since it was just announced very, very recently. But it looks like a good alternative right now.

WebFont Loader:
http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader.html

And this: Google Fonts API
http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

There are also a couple more alternatives which have not been mentioned yet.

Such as [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) and [sIFR](http://novemberborn.net/sifr3). Cufon is Javascript based and sIFR is Flash based