# how to set font family?

Tags: html, css, fonts

my html code-

```
 <div class="logo"><h1><a href="index.html" class="lg">Shizin</a></h1></div>
```

my css code-

```
.lg {
font-family:Monotype Corsiva, Times, serif;
}
```

but it is not working.how can i set font style?

Comment: Using non-standard fonts on a web site is not trivial. See [How to add some non standard font to website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-website)

Comment: Folks, it's nice of you to upvote my comment, but it would be even nicer if you voted to close this as the dupe it really is :)

Answer (score 2):

```
p {
font-family:"Times New Roman",Georgia,Serif;
}
```

This works fine, so do you maybe just have to add the " to Monotype Corsiva, or have to start writing serif with a big S?

---

Update: As you can read from the comment above: Using non-standard fonts on a web site is not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that your system have this font if not then see http://forums.asp.net/p/1467009/3392471.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Font's with spaces in them need to be quoted.

```
font-family: "Times New Roman", Arial, "Trebuchet MS";
```

So :

```
.lg {
   font-family: "Monotype Corsiva", Times, serif;
}
```

Should work fine.