# Can I replace an image with a custom font?

Tags: html, text-styling

On my website I'm currently using image files to represent custom fonts. I'm wondering if I can replace this with actual text but with a font that may not be installed on the viewer's system. How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible (with certain restrictions) using [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/@font-face). For a great introduction, read [this](http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/).

Comment: * Internet Explorer only supports EOT
    * Mozilla browsers support OTF and TTF
    * Safari and Opera support OTF, TTF and SVG
    * Chrome supports TTF and SVG.
If you don't care for IE, then this is a great solution using _only_ a .TTF file. If you need IE support, then a simple JavaScript `if()` would suffice, or use one of those strange `[if ie]` comment tags I can't remember the syntax for!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. I have read quite a bit of it now but it seems too much hassle as JamWaffles pointed out... Since I'm just using the font for title and headers I'll probably just stick to doing images. I really do appreciate it though, thank you.

Comment: Also, I saw on a website using this technique that the highlighting of the text (one of the things I was hoping to achieve) was really messed up. Also (the site may be a bad example) the text was blurred...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a very good choice if you don't mind that the user cannot select and copy your text.

http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/