# Adding Font To A CSS Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, fonts

I have a font I downloaded and I'm trying to apply that font to my site.

so I simply used font-family but my font isn't there(obviously) any idea on how to add it?

Comment: Check out @font-face https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/@font-face

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to embed the font via CSS before you can use it (since most computers probably don't have the font installed locally). Check out:

[CSS Cross Browser Fonts using CSS3 @font-face](http://randsco.com/index.php/2009/07/04/p680)

The cross-browser compatible code ends up looking something like:

```
@font-face 
{  
    font-family: "Your Font Name";  
    src: url(~/Fonts/SomeFontName.eot); /* IE */  
    src: local("The Real Font Name"), 
         url(~/Fonts/FontFileName.ttf) format("truetype"); /* non-IE */  
}  

body
{ 
    font-family:"Your Font Name", verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;  
}
```

Comment: Any licensing issues with @font-face?

Comment: @IrishChieftain - Of course. As with anything else, you have to pay attention to the licensing for the font you are using. Some allow your to freely re-distribute the font. Others don't (and these are the ones you can't use).

Comment: How do I make my CCS version 3? its 2.1 now (Also, format("truetype") is not a valid value for src property)

Comment: @Or Batzalel - You don't have to do anything special.

Answer (score 0):

You simply write the name of the font, such as:

```
font-family: Gotham;
```

.. or ...

```
font-family: "Myriad Pro";
```

It will work on your machine but not on users' machines unless they have the font installed.

Answer (score -1):

I think the question is how can users of your site see the new font?  Try this out:  http://www.howtoplaza.com/how-to-use-custom-fonts-on-your-website-with-css

Such as this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: cool_font;
    src: url('cool_font.ttf');
}
```