# Are non-standard fonts in HTML a bad idea?

Tags: html, fonts, font-face

I am a back-end developer but I am developing a website for a friend, so sorry if this question is stupid.

My friend sent me the layout he wishes and now I am trying to glue everything together with HTML. 
There are some fonts he used that are not the "standard" ones.

Looking in the net, I found this article which explains how to do that:
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/cssatten

But I've also found people saying that non-standard fonts in a website are a bad idea because some browsers may not support it.

Can someone with Web development clarify to me if it is really a bad idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Warning: The article you've read dates back from 2007. Custom fonts are now widely supported. http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface

Comment: Yes, I noticed it after creating my question, thanks :) But my question is now: I know it is widely supported, but is it a good idea? Or is it something that is not recommended?

Comment: It’s not a stupid question, far from that, but it calls for opinions and debate (or discussion), not answers that can be tested and evaluated for technical correctness.

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but **this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.** If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Even if the included font (be it through @font-face, stylesheet rel, JS etc.) fails to be downloaded/included when the CSS is interpreted and the page is rendered, the fallback will be applied. The fallback, being a web safe font (like Arial) means text will still be displayed.

For example:

```
* {
   font-family: "Included Special Font", "Arial", sans-serif;
   /*            ^ Primary               ^ Fallback 1 ^ Fallback 2 */
}
```

Here is a [list of web safe fonts](http://w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp) for your reference.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not at all stupid. Earlier before the release of CSS3, most browsers did not support non standard fonts. It was very difficult from the developer point of view to handle them correctly, but nowadays almost all browsers support non standard fonts and you can use them very easily. Have a look at these articles, they'll help you to decide what's good for you to use in your application:

[Adding non-standard fonts to website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website)

[Thread: Displaying Non-Standard Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bad question, it's quite valid.

And that article has a lot of useful information, like most of the content in that site.

Non standard fonts, used with css are a nice thing to have, but still face many problems ,like compatibility between browsers and support of the formats, in fact, to successfully use a font it an @ rule in all the browsers, you have to use many formats. That's why sites like [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) are so useful and are gaining relevance.

The best way to used them, is to use fallback methods, so at least one of the fonts will be available in the users computer. The problem here, is that most people just chooses fonts kind of similar, but not really equivalent, for instance, you may find rules like `font-family: Futura, Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial`, but those fonts are different, some are wider, some are clearer, etc.

So it boils down to the kind of design you want to use, the respect you have for the user and the time you want to expend with the design. If you want something safe, with low use of bandwith and guaranteed to work, go for the classic ones. If you don't mind a bit more bandwith and are willing to do some trial and error, use @font-face and try services like fontsquirrel. If you really care about the user, then expend time comparing fonts, their sizes and legibility at different sizes, use services like fontquirrel and a safe fallback.

Bye

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is worth a discussion actually. It's not stupid at all, and alot of front end developpers will probably agree on this. Myself, I use costum fonts, but my main focus stays on the standard supported fonts, such as verdanna, arial etc. The costum fonts are just for the markup for headers and stuff. Verdanna, Arial, Times .. they are all developped to make reading more easy on the computer, and in my oppinion, they are still in my top 10 for usage.

This is a personal oppinion though, and I agree, that to some usage costum fonts should be worked with, but if you pick a costum font, look at the readability of a font. Its spacing, its type of letters and all the things that makes a font readable. Importantly, a website has a goal, and is that goal going to be reached if you use that font your friend wants to use. Design is just the extra layer.

I suggest you would some readup on this, and chat with web designers, but they will all agree with me, that the message is more important than the looks.