# CSS Unusual Font

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add some non-standard font to a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website)

I created a website, and in my CSS file Im using a font downloaded from web, it works nice in windows, I can use it on my website, but if I run my page on Linux, of course it do not work because Linux dont know that font, so my question is, if I will put my page on some server, I need to "install" that font on server or something like that, or how does it works?

Comment: you are hosting your own font? see this: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: you need to upload the font to the directory where your other html/css/image  files are located and give correct references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create web-compatible formats (different browsers require different formats) of your font and then use a [`@font-face` rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule) in your stylesheet to include it. For example (this is the output generated by http://fontsquirrel.com):

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "YourFont";
    src: url("YourFont.eot");
    src: url("YourFont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("YourFont.woff") format("woff"),
         url("YourFont.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("YourFont.svg#YourFont") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The browser will then download the appropriate font file and use that.

Answer (score 1):

Fonts are dependent on what font the **client** has installed. There's no use on installing the font on the server.

With CSS3 (not supported by all browsers), you can use the [@font-face CSS property](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/) in order to use custom fonts. Another solution for custom fonts would be the use of [Google Webfonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts). Otherwise, just go for any [web safe font](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp).

Answer (score 0):

If you use a font that is possible not recognized by all systems, you will have to include matching font files on the web server. You can register these fonts using CSS's *@font-face* property.

Try to register a font in multiple formats (like TrueType and OpenType). It's also good practice to provide some fallback fonts which are widely available, like Times New Roman or Arial.