# installing missing fonts on ASP.NET web sites

Tags: asp.net, fonts

I'm working on an ASP.NET web app, which uses unicode language (Persian, Farsi). I want to use fonts that may not exist on all systems, how can I manage the scenario? what happens if a font doesn't exist on a system? I've seen sites that use nice fonts (while I think I don't have these fonts on my system), should I install missing fonts on the first launch? If so, how can I do that (preferably without user prompt)
Also I want to have some backup fonts, for instance I want to have font A, if this font is not usable, I want to switch to font B, how can I do so? what styles should I use? font-family? or font-names?

Comment: I think, this is the [URL][1] you are trying for.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website

Answer (score 1):

You can use the typeface library to embed your fonts on your web pages.

More details, and examples at: http://typeface.neocracy.org/