# Using Typekit fonts with moovweb

Tags: typekit, moovweb

on my proxified site fonts from typekit.com are not imported.

I have this error message in console which seams to be related:

```
 GET http://use.typekit.com/k/yvr5ozi-d.css?3bb2a6e53c9684ffdc9a98f41f5b2a623701…fad90e3287aa7c9eed409223e66627acbb9dbdff991d65ad30b7f969e63cd8681f2fa2879f 403 (Forbidden)
```

What should I do to make fonts embed correctly?

Comment: could you provide a few more details? what does the original HTML markup used to get the font look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nebojsa,

Your getting a 404 because the Typekit servers are rejecting your domain. 
Meaning, every font belongs to a kit in TypeKit, in that kit you need to specify which domains these fonts are served under. If the particular site your working with is not listed here, it will not work and give you a 404.

http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/6857-using-typekit-while-developing-locally

In your case, if your site is catswithclounhats.com and if your serving the font under the virtualized site catswithclounhats.com.moovapp.com then the top level domain (moovapp.com) needs to be included in your kit.

good luck.

Comment: Thanks Omar,

but if so, shouldn't it work at mlocal.catswithclounhats.com ?

Answer (score 1):

When I try going to that link, I get a forbidden error as well.  You probably only have access to it because you might be logged in or have some kind of session going.

I recommend downloading the font file and then placing it in your `assets` directory in your project.  You could even make a new sub-directory called `assets/fonts`.

Then you can use sass to include that font in your pages:

[How to add some non-standard font to a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website)