# Using a specific non-standard font on webpage?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I need to use the font ITC Avant garde Condensed Book and medium but I supose that this is non standard font so how would I go about to make sure that this font is used on the website at the client browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add some non-standard font to a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website)

Comment: All you need to know about this is described here: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
@font-face
{
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url('ITC_Avant_garde_Condensed_Book.ttf'),
     url('ITC_Avant_garde_Condensed_Book.eot'); /* IE9 */
}
```

Read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) more:

> **Remember**
>
> The `@font-face` rule is supported in Internet Explorer 9, Firefox,
>   Opera, Chrome, and Safari.
>
> However, Internet Explorer 9 only supports .eot type fonts, while
>   Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera support .ttf and .otf type fonts.
>
> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, do not support the
>   @font-face rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the font on your server, and then use it in the CSS like:

```
@font-face
{
 font-family:myFamily;
 src:url('your_source_here/fontName.ttf'),
     url('your_source_here/fontName.eot');
 }
```

Since IE8 do not support `@font-face` you should have a fallback font.

To get fonts in different format you can use [the webfont generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)