# Is there any way for pushing fonts into users system

Tags: html, css, fonts

Is there any method for using a font which is not installed in user system.
Till now I knew that font styles are applied in this manner

```
.my-style{
    font-family:Arial, 'Liberation Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

If the  first font is not available in users system it falls back to use the  second font type.

But I observed that Google uses  this font style in `Google+`

```
body{
font: normal 13px Roboto,arial,sans-serif;
}
```

Roboto font is not installed in my PC. Despite of this the Roboto font is used through out `Google+`. I tried using the same font style on sample page but it did not work .

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#at-font-face-rule

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add some non-standard font to a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called @font-face.

http://www.google.com/fonts/ is a good resource/tool for this.

In short, you include a link in your CSS to the fonts, the user downloads and uses them on the site.

They can't access them afterwards, they are only used to draw your website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Webfonts. Google themselves have a wonderful collection of Webfonts...

Check out this wonderful example of using a ***Google Webfont***

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;
        font-size: 48px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Making the Web Beautiful!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Check out this fiddle which shows the working of 2 Google WebFonts. ***Tangerine & Roboto***

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rEmzM/)**