# font face not working

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm having a problem with font face.

I added code to make the font work in my page, but when I type any keywords the font does not work and shows string keywords.

This is the css code:

```
/* @font-face kit by Fonts2u (http://www.fonts2u.com) */ @font-face {font-family:"GE Dinar One Medium";src:url("GE_Dinar_One_Medium.eot?") format("eot"),url("GE_Dinar_One_Medium.woff") format("woff"),url("GE_Dinar_One_Medium.ttf") format("truetype"),url("GE_Dinar_One_Medium.svg#GEDinarOne-Medium") format("svg");font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}

p{font-family:"GE Dinar One Medium";}
```

and this is the html:

```
<p>ahmed mohamed احمد محمد
<br />
انا من مدينة المنصورة مصر
</p>
```

It's just a test, but the font does not work and I'm sure its font url is right. All fonts type are in the same folder

What is the problem?

Comment: How exactly does it not work, what do you see instead? What do you mean by "string keywords"? Does the font come with Arabic characters?

Comment: yes im sure is work for arabic char , lock here http://ar.fonts2u.com/ge-dinar-one-medium.%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D8%B7

Comment: I think you need to post the URL of your page (the real page or a demo page set up to show this problem). It is very common that the font URL is wrong or font loading is prevented, and this can only be seen by testing with a real URL.

Comment: demo link http://elfnoon.com/fonts/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the source of the font family.

See this post
[How to add some non-standard font to a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website)

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: "My Custom Font";
    src: url(http://www.example.org/mycustomfont.ttf) format("truetype");
}
p.customfont { 
    font-family: "My Custom Font", Verdana, Tahoma;
}
</style>
<p class="customfont">Hello world!</p>
```

Comment: i try it but nothing to work :(
http://www.elfnoon.com/demo/kleeja/uploads/1376362721651.png
http://www.elfnoon.com/demo/kleeja/uploads/1376362721852.png
not work at chrome , opera
and work at ie , firefox , safari