# How do I add custom fonts?

Tags: html, css

How do I install a custom font on an html site?

For example, I was working on a wedding website, and I was finding a lot of nice fonts for that subject, but I can't find the right way to add that font to the server, or to include that font with CSS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website?rq=1

Comment: Dive in to @font-face

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Comment: Did you lose google address?

Comment: check out Paul Irishs Blogpost on bullet proof font face. 
http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

download your font and put in any directory. here i added in **fonts** directory

```
   <style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'maven_pro_light_300regular';
        src: url('fonts/mavenprolight-300-webfont.eot');
        src: url('fonts/mavenprolight-300-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('fonts/mavenprolight-300-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('fonts/mavenprolight-300-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('fonts/mavenprolight-300-webfont.svg#maven_pro_light_300regular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    </style>
```

and you can use it by follow example:

```
<style>
h2{
    font-family:maven_pro_light_300regular; 
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have a true type font then you have to use this

```
@font-face
{
 font-family: your_font_name;
 src: url(your_font_folder/font_name.ttf);
}
```

and use it like this

```
h2.title{font-family:your_font_name}
```

or another way to use the Google font API https://www.google.com/fonts

Answer (score 1):

`.my-font{
font-family: font name;
}`

this is the css code.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS3 you can make reference to a font file for use on the HTML page.  Here is some code:

```
<style> 
@font-face
{
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url(fontFILE.woff);
}

div
{
font-family:myFirstFont;
}
</style>
```

The location of the file would be added in place of "fontFILE".  You would just upload the font file along with the HTML page.

Here is a W3Schools article about this:  [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a service like [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) you can make web safe versions of any font you have the rights to use. It also create a stylesheet with everything you need. What's left for you is add the `font-family` in the css and include the css stylesheet in your html page.

Answer (score 1):

Google Fonts has an extensive set of custom fonts that are very easy to install and legally fine to use wherever you like: https://www.google.com/fonts. Just browse and click the fonts you want, then click USE. It'll provide you with all the necessary CSS, and the font files themselves are hosted by Google.

If you want to create an entirely custom web font, you can use FontSquirrel's web font generator (http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). This allows you to upload any True Type font file you already  own and transform it into a web font; it'll also provide you with the necessary CSS though you'll need to host the font files yourself.

Be careful legally with the latter option; not all fonts are licensed to be used on the web.