# Embedding an otf font in an svg

Tags: css, svg, fonts

I have an otf font file (King Basil Lite) and an svg that contains text using that font. My svg file looks like this, but I don't know what to add so the svg can find this font file.
The text says "First Last".

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 310 110" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;"><use xlink:href="#_Image1" x="6" y="11" width="298px" height="88px"/><text x="30.875px" y="52.854px" style="font-family:'KingBasilLite-Regular', 'King Basil Lite';font-size:55px;">First</text><text x="102.452px" y="99.585px" style="font-family:'KingBasilLite-Regular', 'King Basil Lite';font-size:55px;">L<tspan x="136.827px 159.762px 177.032px 200.297px 224.167px 245.892px " y="99.585px 99.585px 99.585px 99.585px 99.585px 99.585px ">ast</tspan></text><defs><image id="_Image1" width="298px" height="88px" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64, [here there's a long encoded piece describing the image]"/></defs></svg>
```

Comment: What is your use case for this file? Distribution on the web? Rendering with a certain rendering program?

Comment: This answer may be helpful: [How do I embed Google Web Fonts into an SVG?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5162/how-do-i-embed-google-web-fonts-into-an-svg#answer-5167)

Comment: @enxaneta unfortunately I'm trying to use a font not on google web fonts.

Comment: @ccprog it's for the web

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21748611/4996779) shortly describes how to self-host fonts, but review the [license terms](https://thehungryjpeg.com/license/terms) to find out if you are allowed to do so.