# How to make custom fonts visible to all users?

Tags: css, layout, fonts

I 'm currently building a website for a language with another person and there is a problem, because a font is necessary to show the alphabet of this language, for which normal characters don't exist. But apparently, however I can view the font, he can't. It is possible for us to put a download-link to the font at our homepage, but I would prefer every user to see it immediately. The CSS is:

```
@font-face {
font-family: gothicw;
src: url("gothic.eot") /* EOT file for IE */
}
@font-face {
font-family: gothicw;
src: url("gothic.ttf") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
```

Comment: What might “for which normal characters don't exist” mean? Make sure you are solving the right problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add some non-standard font to a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website)