# How to use Custom Fonts using CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I have searched this on net found many articles and tutorials, I followed some of them but still not getting the desired results.

I have downloaded the font and place this in the my project folder. This is the code I am writing but it's not changing the font-style.

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: Montereybold;
    src: url(font/Montereybold.ttf);
}

h1
{
    font-size:36px;
    font-family:Montereybold;
}
```

Kindly guide me what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: Go to this url http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: Open the console and see if it throws a 404 "couldn't find file" if it does then your path is probably wrong

Comment: you'll find a several custom fonts here , check it http://www.google.com/fonts

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add some non-standard font to a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Have you tried quoting the font name? Also, for better compatibility, upload several font formats.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montereybold';
    src: url('font/Montereybold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('font/Montereybold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
    url('font/Montereybold.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
    url('font/Montereybold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url('font/Montereybold.svg#Montereybold') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

Using it:

```
font-family:'Montereybold';
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the url is wrong. Is there "font" folder in parent folder of your css file ? Otherwise,  try "../font/Montereybold.ttf".

Also, ttf is not supported by all browser. Use font-face generator for a best result : http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator .