# Using downloaded font offline

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have just downloaded a google-font. I want to use it in a specific section of the page. I think I am using the font in an incorrect manner.

```
.page-header {
    font-family: 'Calligraffitti', cursive;
    src : url('../fonts/Calligraffitti/Calligraffitti-Regular.ttf');
}
```

If this is incorrect, could you tell me the correct way of using a font that is not installed on a system?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website go through this

Comment: If you are offline meaning not connected to the internet, then you just need to make sure the path to your local font file is correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this at the top of your CSS document.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Calli;
    src: url('../fonts/Calligraffitti/Calligraffitti-Regular.ttf');
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
.page-header {
    font-family: Calli;
}
```

Comment: and add `font family` for `.page-header`  `.page-header {font-family: Calli;}`

Comment: If there are multiple fonts to be used, could we add multiple `@font-face` to`css`?