# Add font to a specific div in HTML5 and CSS

Tags: css, html, fonts

I have a font font.tff and want to add it to the following html code. I want to add it only to the menu, @font-face I saw it changes the font to all the text. How can I add it with CSS? Thank you.

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>menu 1</li>
    <li>menu 2</li>
    <li>menu 3</li>
    <li>menu 4</li>
    <li>menu 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I used the following:

```
<style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: "Your typeface";
                   src: url("ffan.tff");
    }
    #menu { 
      font-family: "Your typeface";
    }
</style>
```

but doens't modify anything.

Comment: `@font-face` just includes the font but doesn't change the font of all the text unless you set that on a class definition ..... so you need font-face and after do `#menu li { font-family: 'yourfont'}`

Comment: Are there any styles on the ul or li tags specifying a different font? Also be sure the browser you're using recognizes 'tff'.

Comment: @BSMP no, no other fonts; I'm using Chrome, lastest version.

Comment: Seems like this ought to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website?rq=1 since the answer shows how to use if for just a paragraph tag.

Comment: Please add related CSS, the code you provided should work as is http://jsfiddle.net/mj21ksgw/

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Your typeface";
  src: url("type/filename.eot");
  url("type/filename.woff") format("woff"),
  url("type/filename.otf") format("opentype"),
  url("type/filename.svg#filename") format("svg");
}

#menu { 
  font-family: "Your typeface", Georgia, serif; 
}
```

Comment: That's what I was writing.. :)

Answer (score 1):

With @font-face, you specify a font that you can use on your page, but you don't have to use it everywhere.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "myFirstFont";
  src: url("type/filename.eot");
  url("type/filename.woff") format("woff"),
  url("type/filename.otf") format("opentype"),
  url("type/filename.svg#filename") format("svg");
}
```

For instance, you can specify fonts for the body:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; 
}
```

And still use myFirstFont on the menu:

```
#menu {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```