# Font works locally but not on server

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, filezilla

I'm using a font called downlink for my site and I've run into an issue.  Everything works perfectly fine when I test my site locally, but when I upload it to the server (via Filezilla) the font is not loaded.

Here's my CSS code for the font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: downlink;
    src: url(../fonts/downlink.otf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: downlink;
    src: url(../fonts/downlinkBold.otf);
    font-weight:bold;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: downlink;
    src: url(../fonts/downlinkItalic.otf);
    font-style:italic;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: downlink;
    src: url(../fonts/downlinkBoldItalic.otf);
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
}
```

I'm quite sure that I've uploaded everything I needed to with Filezilla because if I download all my server contents (well the public html contents) to an empty folder and run it from there, the site still works.

So I'm running dry on ideas to fix this, any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is it meant to be GET hhtps?

Comment: The errors in the console also contain a status code and message, you should include this information. Otherwise it is not clear if it is  e.g. not found or forbidden.

Comment: Out of curiousity, I looked for the list of font file name extensions: http://fileinfo.com/filetypes/font seems **.oft** does not include on the list? or my technology is outdated? correct me if Im wrong. Thanks

Comment: @Vainglory07 pretty sure it is a type like `hhtps` is. The css file shows `.otf`. But it is bad the _copied_ error  has typos.

Comment: 1) Why your url contains `www.'mysite'.co.za`? 2) You request `.oft`, but in CSS you specify `.otf` file.

Comment: my url is just called 'mysite' to represent where my site is, don't feel like giving it away right now.  Sorry for all the typos fixed them now and just realized that my console errors were from previous sessions that I ran, so there aren't any console errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I think you didn't Properly Embed our Font.
Please take your font (TTF) format and try to convert Webfont using [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) or any other converter, than upload your font and style sheet to your server

Comment: You have regular, italic, bold, boldItalic But all the font have same family name in your @font-face rule please check, or embed your font properly.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks!   And this helps for all those cross-platform issues we may run into later...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. First check if your font is accessible through the combined URL.
2. Second open the webpage and check (using chrome Inspector for
   instance) if the URL is building correctly.
3. If none of the shows errors check if the webserver allows the MIME
   type to be accessed/downloaded
4. Check this answer to see if it is not a browser support issue: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website)

Hope this helps.