# Local font not applied in web page in .net, How to import font

Tags: html, css, vb.net, fonts

[image]I have included font like this, I am good in html but i dont know vb.net . In normal css if I include as given below it will work but in .net it is not so..

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url('../fonts/Oswald Light.woff2'), url('../fonts/Oswald-Light.woff2') format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url('../fonts/Oswald Light.woff2'), url('../fonts/Oswald-Light.woff2') format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/Oswald Regular.woff2'), url('../fonts/Oswald-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
```

I have respective files in respective folders too..

Comment: Are you sure the file paths are correct? Can you check the Network tab in devtools?

Comment: yes, in normal html we can view the files in browser right..but here i cant view using the path in browser.. see the screenshot attached

Answer (score 0):

Check your paths... using `../fonts` will take the path **back** a directory from wherever you use this file. You may need to use `~/fonts` which will use the root of the web app as a starting point.

Comment: tried but it didn't worked...C:\Techbase 4.0\Techbase\Techbase\Content2\oswald.css **css path**  C:\Techbase 4.0\Techbase\Techbase\fonts **Fonts Path**..

Comment: I'm not familiar with this functionality but after several searches the common format used for URL is the full website address in most examples I have seem. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website?rq=1