# Why do my fonts look different in my Google Chrome Browser?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, browser, fonts

I changed the fonts on my blog a few days, but the changes still haven't appeared in my Google Chrome Browser. I do see the changes on all other of my devices including the Google Chrome browser on my other computer. This is what it's supposed to look like.
[image]

But this is what it looks like in the browser I changed the fonts with.
[image]

However it doesn't look like this in any other browser or another device. What could be wrong? My website is www.dianametdanny.com if you want to check for yourself.

Comment: What font did you use? Did you include the font link in your page? Not all browsers can display all fonts, which is why many webdevs choose to define 2 or 3 fonts in order to make sure it looks OK on all browsers. If your font isn't included in Chrome, it won't work. [relevant SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website).

Comment: This shouldn't be the problem though. I have seen my website in a google chrome browser on another computer and it looks like the first image. The way it's supposed to be.

Comment: hello, i couldn't comment earlier for lack of reputation so i gave it as an answer instead, but i need more information on one point. Did you try using a private session windows as i suggested in the comment ? Tell me if you have the good fonts or not so it will be easier to guess what the problem is.

Comment: If the website displays correctly on all devices and browsers except your Chrome browser, it is indeed most likely a caching issue as @Carele said Have you tried CTRL-F5 (or CMD-F5) to force a full refresh?

Comment: Yes Carele it worked. Thanks. How do I make your answer the final one to my question?

Comment: What is the reason why this happened in the first place?

Comment: @DianaBohorquez I expanded my answer so you may understand what is a cache and how it works. Feel free to ask more questions about it ! To mark it as the final answer you have to click on the "V" checkmarch under the arrows where you upvote/downvote.

Comment: wow thanks @tijmen i never knew about ctrl + f5... I always cleared the cache... The trick will definitely serve !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably the fonts are cached. Try looking at your website in a "private navigation" window, it should be fine. You might or might not want to clear your cache after that (if it works correctly on private navigation, it will work correctly after you clear your cache).

Also note that your browser may not support that font, and this might also be a reason why your font don't look the same.

**More informations :**
Many informations (such as font, passwords, images...) are stored in your computer memory to lower loading time everytime you try to load that same page. That is what the cache is. Basically everytime you load the page, your browser will try to see if you have things in your computer memory before loading them from the web. In this case, you may have the font saved in your computer memory.
By the way i believe there is a developer mode in wordpress (i don't have one right now to check). If you have no visitors yet, you might want to enable that dev mode so that nothing will be stored in cache and it will be easier for you to edit it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. I had to clear my browser, and it worked.