# Why is the font not showing in my text?

Tags: html, css

I have used the font Arial Rounded MT Bold for my H1 heading through CSS. I have the font installed on my computer. But it still won't show when I preview the HTML file.

HTML:

```
<h1>CSS-Tricks</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
color:#FFF;
font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", "Helvetica Rounded", Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 65px;
font-weight: 100;
line-height:25px;
padding:30px;
}
```

Sorry for basic question but I am new to HTML/CSS.

Comment: try without `Bold`, use `font-weight: 900`

Comment: You could take a look there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website

Comment: problem is color you have given white

Comment: Try to change the color you are using for your font

Answer (score 3):

You can put color is different because by default background color is `white` and you can put different color

**HTML**

```
<h1>CSS-Tricks</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
 h1 {
    color:red;
    font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", "Helvetica Rounded", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 65px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height:25px;
    padding:30px;
    }
```

Font Red Color Demo [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/o8ms562t/)

Font White Color Demo [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/o8ms562t/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Because #FFF is white color, try changing the color into other.