# Failed to decode downloaded font in my website

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

This is an error I am getting in my site. unfortunately searching for it hasn't given me much results.

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://mysite/testing/site1/revolution/fonts/revicons/revicons90c6-2.html?5510888
```

index.php#tab3:1 OTS parsing error: invalid version tag

My CSS are these:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'revicons';
src: url('../fonts/revicons/revicons90c6.html?5510888');
src: url('../fonts/revicons/revicons90c6.html?5510888#iefix') 
 format('embedded-opentype'),
   url('../fonts/revicons/revicons90c6-2.html?5510888') format('woff'),
   url('../fonts/revicons/revicons90c6-3.html?5510888') format('truetype'),
   url('../fonts/revicons/revicons90c6-4.html?5510888#revicons') 
   format('svg');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
  }
```

Comment: What font are you trying to include? FontAwesome or Revicons? Because the error is for FontAwesome and the CSS is for Revicons

Comment: sorry......this is my error                                                                                         Failed to decode downloaded font: http://mysite/testing/site1/revolution/fonts/revicons/revicons90c6-2.html?5510888
index.php#tab3:1 OTS parsing error: invalid version tag

Comment: What happens when you navigate to that url in your browser?

Comment: Also it's a bit strange you include font files as html files...

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22738998/6029290

Comment: Have you properly converted the fonts to .WOFF, .EOT, TTF etc.? Try placing your URL in the browser's addressbar and see what is the message you are getting.

Comment: it's working now..it was my mistake to include font files as html files.