# Adding custom font using @fontface to style.css

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have a custom font I would like to use on a webpage. Specifically    GT-Walsheim-Pro-Medium-Oblique.woff from:
https://andrewsonline.co.uk/content/fonts/

The style.css I am working with is this:
https://github.com/syunghong/veil/blob/master/css/style.css

How do I incorperate this font file using @fontface into my style.css file?
I have GT-Walsheim-Pro-Medium-Oblique.woff in a folder called fonts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add some non-standard font to a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website)

Comment: Right, im just not sure where to put @fontface within what I already have though...where does it go - exactly?

Comment: Usually at the top of the CSS file.

Comment: Before index? And does that mean I need to remove anything from:  `html, body {
    height: 100%;  
    width: 100%;  
    margin: 0;  
  color:#111111;   
  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;  
  font-size:21px;  
  font-weight:300;  
  letter-spacing:0.1px;  
  word-spacing:0.5px;  
}`

Answer (score 0):

here

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'RobotoBold'; /*this is what you put on your font family*/
  src: url('../fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf'); /*Link to the font*/
}
```

to use it

```
p {
   font-family: RobotoBold;
   font-size: 14;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, im just not sure where to put @fontface within what I already have though...where does it go - exactly?  In: https://github.com/syunghong/veil/blob/master/css/style.css

Comment: edited it with example :) Edit:. I messed up, it is RobotoBold, not RobotoMedium.. Already edited it anyway.

Comment: Hey thanks. Im just not sure how to incorperate this with what im already using, which is https://github.com/syunghong/veil/blob/master/css/style.css

Answer (score 0):

If you own the rights to use the webfont, take the original ttf or otf font and render a full set [here at FontSquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). Different browsers prefer different font types, the older browsers are pickiest.

Then add the font to the top of your stylesheet so it's loaded first or even before the stylesheet inline if you see FOUT, "Flash of Unstyled Text". [More info here](https://css-tricks.com/fout-foit-foft/) but basically you want the font loaded and ready before your html starts loading.

Then load your font like this:

```
   @font-face {
      font-family: 'GT Walsheim Pro Medium Oblique';
      src: url('GT-Walsheim-Pro-Medium-Oblique.eot');
      src: url('GT-Walsheim-Pro-Medium-Oblique.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('GT-Walsheim-Pro-Medium-Oblique.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('GT-Walsheim-Pro-Medium-Oblique.woff') format('woff'),
      url('GT-Walsheim-Pro-Medium-Oblique.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('GT-Walsheim-Pro-Medium-Oblique.svg') format('svg');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }
```

Font Squirrel will output the above code for you when you render the font package there.

Call the font in your css like this, I'm using your H titles as an example, make sure to always have a fallback for the font in case it errors or doesn't load for some reason:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: 'GT Walsheim Pro Medium Oblique', arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And im putting this at the top of the css file here: https://github.com/syunghong/veil/blob/master/css/style.css?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't look like it will render there, but will render on a webserver or GitHub custom web page.

Comment: I mean, where am I literally putting @fontace within this style.css?

Comment: At the top, before index?

Comment: Yes at the very top. Always load the fontface as soon as you can, that usually means either top of the css file or inline in the head (depends on what works best for your situation).