# How to get the font family of a font, Is font name is the font family?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am a newbie in web developement. I have to use dodger font.
I have all ttf ,otf ,svg files.
How to get the font family of a font , is there anyway i can find the font famiy.
I have googled a lot, but no luck

Comment: You need to add the Dodger font to your website, check out this stack overflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add some non-standard font to a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website)

Comment: You misunderstand CSS: CSS is under *your* control, and you get to *dictate* to the browser what CSS should load when you give it *whatever* font family name. `@font-face { font-family: whateverNameYouWant; src: url(...); }` tells CSS that whenever you use `font-family: whatevernameYouWant` in your site CSS, the render engine **must** load the font that you said went with that font family name.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to import font files:

```
@font-face { 
font-family: "MyFont"; 
src: url("/pathToFonts/myfont.ttf"); 
}
```

Usage:

```
p{
font-family: "MyFont";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So font name is the font family

Comment: What ever you like. You can call it "FontyMacFontFace" if you like. But better the filename of your font.

Comment: In your case it should look like:
@font-face { 
font-family: "Dodger"; 
src: url("/pathToFonts/dodger.ttf");  #However the file is named.
}

Comment: However, do not use the .ttf or .otf font directly. Wrap them as WOFF or WOFF2, because using a *universal OpenType system font* for the web in 2017 (coming up to 2018) makes about as much sense as using TIFF instead of JPG or PNG. Take advantage of what WOFF does for fonts.